# change margin and gravity collapsed title in toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I try to use custom toolbar with 2 icon and RelativeLayer and append CollapsingToolbarLayout for Collapsing title and image but title text overlay on right icon and padding not work

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="64dp"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppBar"
            app:paddingStart="10dp"
            app:paddingEnd="10dp"
            app:contentScrim="#ffffff"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/about_img"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                app:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
            <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingRight="10dip"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:id="@+id/re_toolbar">
                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/img_menu" android:src="@drawable/menu_icon" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:paddingTop="10dip"/>
                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/img_header_info"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_header_info" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:paddingTop="5dip"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

style file :

```
    <style name="CollapsedAppBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
```

but i cannot change text margin and text align .

need margin :

[image: title need margin]
[image: title need margin]

Need align :

[image]

and dependencies :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by using LinearLayout with horizontal orientation instead of RelativeLayout.
Put both ImageViews inside LinearLayout. LinearLayout does not allows its child to overlap each other.
You can also add headline as a title of toolbar.
Try this method:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```

Comment: test this point does not work ,still The headline over the photo placed

Comment: I try use image parallax collapsed toolbar and use CollapsingToolbar.setTitle("TITLE"); for set title . if use getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TITLE");  title dose not show